# Excel: How to use LEFT function on a Date formatted cell?

Tags: excel, date, format

I am trying to extract the time string from date and time in a cell. I apply the `LEFT` function in my Excel: in Cell `E1`, the date and time are shown `"2017/9/1  12:02:01"`.In Cell `D1`, I used `=LEFT(E1,8)` to extract the string `"12:02:01"`, but it returned `"42979.00"`. It seems like the cell is treated as a number, not a date and time format. How should I fix this? I run Excel on iOS.

Here is a screenshot of the cells `D1` and `E1`:

[image]

Comment: change the format of the cell E1 to Time, and make it = D1

Comment: A date is just a number in Excel starting at 1 on 01/01/1900  To the left of the decimal place is the date, to the right is the time.  The number you're seeing represents 42979 days after 01/01/1900 - as @Harun24HR states in his answer, just format it to show the time only.

Answer (score 3):

If it is date formatted the use below formula-

```
=TEXT(E1,"hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: This also works if you need to extract the date portion like I did. Change the formula to (adjust for whatever date format you need):  
`=TEXT(E1, "yyyy-mm-dd")`